# Structuring array data for a soap client connection in php

Tags: php

I am connecting via soap to a remote system to pull information and would like some help on how to pass an array of data durring connection.  Right now, this code works correctly;

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://host:8443/realtimeservice/services/RisPort?wsdl", array('stream_context' => $context, trace'=>true, 'login' => "login",'password'=> "password"));
$array['SelectBy'] = "Name";
$array['Status'] = "Any";
$array['SelectItems']['SelectItem[0]']['Item'] = "deviceName";
$devices = $soapClient->SelectCmDevice("", $array);
```

I would like to condense it into the $device variable so that I don't have separate array statements.  It feels like it should kind of look like this;

```
$devices = $soapClient->SelectCmDevice("", array('SelectBy'=>'Name','Status'=>'Any',?));
```

However, I don't know how to write the third object.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work. I appreciate the minimalist approach, but this looks worse imho and is really difficult for another coder to read.  4 understandable lines is better than 1 cryptic line.

```
$devices = $soapClient->SelectCmDevice("", array('SelectBy'=>'Name','Status'=>'Any','SelectItems'=>array('SelectItem[0]'=>array('Item'=>"deviceName"))));
```

Comment: Thanks, RightClick.  I'm still weighing issues of clarity with this code.  I'm thinking of extending it and wanted to keep it tidy from the start.